# How to patch libgphoto2 for preview pictures in Shotwell while importing?

Tags: 12.04, shotwell, patch

Under some circumstances, Shotwell shows no photo thumbnails while importing. 
I was trying to download some pictures from my camera (Canon EOS 400D) with Shotwell and the program didn't show any preview for the pictures before downloading them (it just shows a "forbidden" snapshot). After importing them everything seems fine.

I've found this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgphoto2/+bug/986676) but no solution is given for now. It seems there could be a solution for EOS cameras, according to the [last comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgphoto2/+bug/986676/comments/10). This guy links to a patch, but it's not downloadable. Any ideas of where to obtain a deb package of this patch or of any other solution?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the ["Patch" link](http://gphoto.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gphoto/branches/libgphoto2-2_4/libgphoto2/camlibs/ptp2/library.c?view=patch&r1=14007&r2=14020&pathrev=14020) you can then save the patch as a .diff file and apply it against trunk.

You can get a copy of gphoto's working trunk with

```
svn co https://gphoto.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gphoto gphoto
```

Applying the patch is something akin to this command:

```
patch -p1 < gphoto.diff
```

(Note: I haven't actually tried this, but I believe it will work.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. Since I didn't know how to use the svn trunks I simply downloaded libgphoto2 from [the official sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gphoto/files/). I changed manually the lines in library.c, just exactly as in the patch. However, after compiling it (doing the typical "configure", "make", "sudo checkinstall", and having downloaded lsusb-dev from repositories) it seems Ubuntu doesn't do anything when I connect the camera, so that I can't download the pictures. In any case, if I write lsusb in the terminal I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04a9:3110 Canon, Inc. EOS Digital Rebel XTi
```

So strictly speaking the OS detects the camera, but it does nothing.

Since I was having this problem, I came with another solution. It's not as *elegant* as compiling it, but it worked. The idea is just to download the official Ubuntu 11.10 libgphoto2 package [from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgphoto2/2.4.11-3) . Then in a terminal you just type:

```
sudo dpkg -i libgphoto2-2_2.4.11-3_(architecture).deb
```

Now it is possible to see all the pics, although it is done in the "old way" (this version doesn't have the "EOS fast directory" enabled).